# J2ME Push notifications API Documentation

Tags: java

I would like to implement push notifications for J2ME devices but I can't find proper API documentation. I tried Microsoft's website but only found forums where they are just discussing issues that they are experiencing. Can someone advice where I can find any documentation for push notifications.

Comment: Are you sure about using J2ME platform? It's outdated and community support is almost non-existent.

Comment: I would like to cater for people who are still using nokia usha and others like nokia c3,c1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to do this for nokia devices that are S40_6th_edition onwards.
But you will have to contact nokia (notifications.support@nokia.com)directly for this type of api's.